# Как использовать неопубликованный пакет?

Tags: node.js, npm

Я написал небольшой gulp-плагин для своего текущего проекта. Я не хочу его опубликовывать, т.к. он имеет смысл только в рамках моего проекта. Проблема в том, что когда я делаю что-либо с помощью npm, мой плагин удаляется из node_modules. Я попытался добавить его в package.json, но теперь при использовании npm я получаю ряд ошибкок:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/<название пакета> - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '<название пакета>@^1.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Отсюда, собственно вопрос: как мне использовать пакет, не опубликовывая его, и возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `package.json` можно писать пакеты со ссылкой на любой git-репозиторий, например:

```
"some-my-package": "git+ssh://git@example.com:smth/some-my-package.git#1.1.18"
```